# Formatting the output in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having some issue in printing output...

My code:

```
def main():
    total = 0
    capital = ["Bern", "London", "Washington D.C"]
    country = ["Switzerland", "England", "America"]
    population = [0.126,8.539,0.659]
    print "   Capital\tCountry\t\tPopulation"
    print "-------------\t-------------\t-------------"
    for i in range(len(capital)):
        print "%s\t%s\t%s"% (capital[i-1], country[i-1], population[i-1])
main()
```

Output:

```
   Capital      Country         Population
-------------   -------------   -------------
Washington D.C  America 0.659
Bern    Switzerland     0.126
London  England 8.539
```

I am trying to make the output look like this:

```
   Capital         Country        Population
-------------   -------------   -------------
Washington D.C     America          0.659
Bern             Switzerland        0.126
London             England          8.539
```

I have tried a lot to adjust output by adding and reducing '\t' but couldn't adjust it...

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings), as follows, as it has better text formating with string adjustments and all sort of stuff that would make the output printed prettier:

```
>>> def main():
    capital = ["Bern", "London", "Washington D.C"]
    country = ["Switzerland", "England", "America"]
    population = [0.126,8.539,0.659]
    print '{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}'.format(*['Capital','Country','Population'])
    print '{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}'.format(*['-'*12]*3)
    for cap,cout,pop in zip(capital,country,population):
        print '{:<15}{:^15}{:^15}'.format(cap,cout,pop)


>>> main()
    Capital        Country      Population   
 ------------   ------------   ------------  
Bern             Switzerland       0.126     
London             England         8.539     
Washington D.C     America         0.659
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a minimum field width to the `%` operator in the `print` call. For example:

```
print "%24s" % ("Bern")
```